# Protocol design in C++, cyclic class membership

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm (attempting) to design a communication protocol in C++ and want to abstract away the various layers of the protocol so they can be changed in the future if need be without having to change the whole app.

So far, I've designed this:

1. Application --- eg. climate->SetTemperature(70);
2. Module (eg. Climate) --- eg. protocol->SetRegister(23, 70);
3. Protocol Layer --- eg. msg[] = {0x4C, 0x55, 0x17, 0x46};
   comm->SendPacket(msg);
4. Communication layer

The problem occurs on the return path:

1. Communication layer
2. Protocol Layer
3. Module
4. Application

I don't really want the application constantly asking the module for data, and then the module asking the protocol, and the protocol asking the communication layer, but callbacks in each of the classes to "bubble up" the data seems messy. Generally though, only the Communication layer will know if there's any data worth processing further (byt the Protocol layer and so on)

Is there a better design pattern?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This is standard stuff. [Events and observers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Messy? I dunno, everybody does it.

Comment: Messy as in there's only ever a single observer for each event, and the protocol and module will be both subjects and observers - the protocol will be observing the communication and the module will be observing the protocol for example, plus the module will be using the protocol and the protocol using the communication (ie, it's two way). So I don't think the design pattern fits the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that you are not doing synchronous communication, so you can't wait until the Communication Layer has the answer.

So what we have is Application->Module->Protocol->Communication. That all for the transmit side (apart from any retries, etc from the various layers).

You don't say how the data is actually collected, chances are the Communication Layer will not know about any data until you tell it as the message/event system is in the app. So you need to call it anyway, and it seems wrong for the app to know about both the modules and all the communication layers.

So pass the collected data to the Modules and let them pass it down the chain, if the data is meaningful it'll eventually reach the top layer. The application should 'subscribe' to events from the modules to get the data required (events and observers). Subscriptions are not required between the layers of the communication as you'll be calling them to give them the work anyway, so they can simply return the result of the processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like you were the only person that actually understood what I wrote :)